# Послать реакту событие об изменении checkbox'а

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь через `dispatchEvent` послать событие так, чтобы React его обработал, но по какой-то причине обработчик `onChange` в реакте не вызывается, хотя все нативные обработчики вызываются как и должны:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('input', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: "chk",
    onChange: function (e) { console.log("react") } // Не вызывается :(
  }),
  document.querySelector("main")
);

var chk = document.getElementById("chk")

chk.addEventListener('change', function (e) { console.log("native") });
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) { console.log("native + bubbling") });
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) { console.log("native + capturing") }, true);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(">>> DISPATCH BEGIN");
  
  chk.checked = !chk.checked;
  
  var e = document.createEvent("Events");
  e.initEvent('change', true, true);
  chk.dispatchEvent(e);
  
  console.log(">>> DISPATCH END");
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
<button>Dispatch</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. React хочет получить событие `click`, а не `change`.
2. Отправка клика сама инвертирует значение чекбокса, поэтому эту строку надо убрать.

Получается такой код:

```
var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initEvent('click', true, true);
chk.dispatchEvent(e);
```

который можно упростить до

chk.click();

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('input', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: "chk",
    onChange: function (e) { console.log("react") }
  }),
  document.querySelector("main")
);

var chk = document.getElementById("chk")

chk.addEventListener('change', function (e) { console.log("native") });
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) { console.log("native + bubbling") });
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) { console.log("native + capturing") }, true);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(">>> DISPATCH BEGIN");
  
  ////var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  ////e.initEvent('click', true, true);
  ////chk.dispatchEvent(e);

  chk.click();
  
  console.log(">>> DISPATCH END");
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
<button>Dispatch</button>
```